# Encapsulating requireJS and its modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'd like to use something like `requireJS` to modularise my javascript app, however, there's one particular requirement I'd like to meet that I haven't figured out:

I'm happy enough to have `require` and `define` in the global space, however, I **don't** want modules that I import with `require` to be accessible globally (i.e. they should be accessible to my app, but not other apps running on the same page).

It seems to me that if I call `define('moduleA', function() { ... });` I can then access that module - globally - via the `require` function. It may not be occupying a variable in the global space itself, or be attached to `window`, but it still *feels* bad, because other apps really shouldn't be able to see my internal modules (not to mention potential naming conflicts, etc, can I use `contexts` to circumvent this?).

This seems to be a step back from just namespacing my modules and including them all inside of one big privatising function at build time.

I could have my own private version of `require` but my modules (being in different files) wouldn't be able to access `define`.

Am I missing something or do I just have to live with this? (or alternatively, run an optimizer to bake everything into one file - feels like I could just namespace my modules and not bother with `requireJS` at all if I do that though).

Answer (score 0):

In your r.js build config add `wrap: true` and you will no longer pollute the glabal scope with `require` or `define` functions.

**Edit**:

You can also specify a namespace for your `require` and `define` with the `namespace` setting in the r.js build config. You can [read more about namespacing in RequireJS's FAQ](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#rename). From the [example.build.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L291) comments:

```
// Allows namespacing requirejs, require and define calls to a new name.
// This allows stronger assurances of getting a module space that will
// not interfere with others using a define/require AMD-based module
// system. The example below will rename define() calls to foo.define().
// See http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#rename for a more
// complete example.
namespace: 'foo',
```

Comment: Wrapping require/define is easy, but then my modules can't see them (when loaded from other files).